# How to get Delete confirmation from user before the delete query using php

Tags: javascript, php

Below is my delete code using php,I want to get confirmation after delete link was clicked from the user using php.

```
 <?php
 include('conn.php');
 $query=mysql_query("DELETE FROM mark WHERE student_id='$_GET[st_id]'");
 if($query)
    {
        echo ("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
    window.alert('Succesfully deleted')
    window.location.href='mark-details1.php';
    </SCRIPT>");
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Check your Server";
    }
    ?>
```

Please anyone can tell me how to do this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: 1: NEVER have a link that calls a delete - one visit from Google spider and your database is empty. 2. Ajax the request using `method: "DELETE"` and show the return message

Comment: Please do not use `mysql_*` functions anymore. They are deprecated in PHP5 and removed in PHP7. Use MySQLi or PDO prepared statements instead to prevent mysql injections.

Comment: @mplungjan nothing is wrong if delete is behind authentication part.

Comment: Yes. ONE user with a prefetch plugin will do the same - Just don't!

Comment: Link is an another file that is called based on the id

Comment: <a class="wh" href="edit-mark.php?st_id=<?=$rows['student_id']?>" title="Edit">Edit Marks</a> this is link point from another link

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use this javascript event on your html tag.

```
onclick="return confirm('you sure?');"
```

you can also use this :
if your link will send a get like "?delete=(id)"

```
<?php
include('conn.php');
if(isset($_GET['delete']) && is_numeric($_GET['delete'])==1){
    echo (a page with a form with confirmation question content that will sent a get for example (?checked_delete=(id)));
}elseif(isset($_GET["checked_delete"]) && is_numeric($_GET["checked_delete"])==1){
    // TODO : deleting record.
    $query=mysql_query("DELETE FROM mark WHERE student_id='$_GET[checked_delete]'");
    header("location:mark-details1.php")
}else{
    echo (normal page);
}
?>
```

Comment: It is not normally a good idea to have inline event handlers. In this case a link to a delete, visited by a spider will completely ignore your script

Comment: There is not any speak about spiders on this question. This will work on normal conditions very well.

Comment: *I* speak about spiders. If you have a link that deletes something on the server, any javascript will be ignored by automated scripts or prefetch plugins and the delete will be executed regardless of your alert

Comment: this event will occur before sending data to db. and if he want to check the confirmation before deleting he should  use php coding. and it's like to create a page for it. so easy to talk about.

Comment: Only in a browser with JavaScript enabled

Comment: @Jer that is not true. Returning false onclick will cancel the click

Comment: every browsers have javascript enable these days. and if not , it's their problem. yes. I used this code so many times.

Comment: That does not make it a good idea. I am not talking about browsers - I am talking about your page full of delete links being visited by a spider or loaded by a user with a prefetch plugin: ALL links are called.

Comment: this is a solution for a lot of places. for panel to be used by admins for example. but if we should use confirmation for visitors , we can use another solution that is more secure. there is a lot of solutions. but this is a solution too.

Comment: Which is why I removed my downvote because it actually does answer the question

Comment: onclick="return confirm('you sure?');" will works me ! thanks !

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using Ajax. Here I will use jQuery to do it

```
<a class="wh" data-id="<?=$rows['student_id']?>" href="edit-mark.php?st_id=<?=$rows['student_id']?>" title="Edit">Edit Marks</a><span class="confirmation"></span>
```

using

```
$(function() {
  $(".wh").on("click",function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // cancel the click
    $.get(this.href,function(data) { // does the student still exist?
      if (confirm("delete" +data+"?")) {
        $.get("otherphp.php?st_id="+$(this).data("id"),function(data) { 
          $(this).next().html(data);  // show response
        });
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Or to hide the href from spiders

```
<a class="wh" href="onlyworkswithjavascript.html" 
data-id="<?=$rows['student_id']?>" data-href="edit-mark.php?st_id=<?=$rows['student_id']?>" 
title="Delete">Delete Marks</a><span class="confirmation"></span>


$(function() {
  $(".wh").on("click",function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // cancel the click
    if (confirm("delete" +data+"?")) {
      $.get($(this).data("href"),function(data) { 
        $(this).next().html(data);  // show response
      });
    }
  });
});
```